# Stream that has separate write and read positions

Tags: c#, stream

I want to emulate a network-type stream on a single PC.

I've done this by creating a `Stream` that takes in 2 underlying streams, one to read from and another to write to.

I then create 2 instances of this class swapping the 2 streams. Currently I'm using `MemoryStream`s as the 2 underlying streams.

The trouble i have now is that if I write X bytes to a `MemoryStream` then its position will be X and if i then do a `Read` I get no data, as i'm at the end of the stream.

Given that I'll typically be doing a couple of reads/writes (so can't just reset the postion to 0 after every write) **what `Stream` can i use to get this behaviour?**

**Effectively I want a sort of byte queue that I can write to and read to in the form of a stream.**

i.e. (ignoring actual method arguments)

```
MyStream.Write({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
MyStream.Write({ 7, 8 });
MyStream.Read(3) // Returns { 1, 2, 3 }
MyStream.Read(4) // Returns { 4, 5, 6, 7 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's actually a lot simpler than I thought (in my case anyway).
I simply restore/record the read/write positions before performing any operation:

```
public class QueueStream : MemoryStream
{
    long ReadPosition;
    long WritePosition;

    public QueueStream() : base() { }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        Position = ReadPosition;

        var temp = base.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        ReadPosition = Position;

        return temp;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        Position = WritePosition;

        base.Write(buffer, offset, count);

        WritePosition = Position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only issue is this code isn't thread safe. If you're using this code with multiple threads, you'll want to make sure nothing attempts to call read and write at the same time. Above the Read and Write methods you can add [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] to be (thread) safe.